What Happens On The RabbitMQ Cluster When a MassTransit Consumer Implementing the Request/Response Pattern Doesn't Respond?
My team and I are working on trying MassTransit and RabbitMQ with the request/response pattern.  We want to give the DevOps team high level visibility into the state of the system.
We were playing around yesterday.  We’re implementing a Dynatrace agent on the cluster.
Right now, we can see a list of all the Queues and Exchanges and we can see the total number of requests in the queue and the number of requests processed, etc.  But, we can’t see the failed responses.
Currently, we have a producer and a consumer.  We’re implementing the Request/Response pattern.
The consumer sends a request.
The request shows up in the queue called .
There’s also a queue and exchange called _testhost_bus_someId.  I think that under the hood, what’s happening is that the message goes here and then is re-routed to the actual queue that it needs to go to. (I would love an explanation or at least a picture of what happens under the hood).
Yesterday, we put some logic in our consumer.  We had the  consumer fail to respond to a percentage of the requests, like so.
`
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext context)
{
 //. . . Do Stuff

 Logger.WriteLine($"request consumed...");
 
 if (ShouldRespond())
  {
     context.Respond(new MyResponseType
         {
             //. . .
         });
     Logger.WriteLine($"Response sent from consumer);
  }
  else
  {
     Logger.WriteLine($"Response NOT sent from consumer);
  }

}
`
We were expecting to see the messages be in the queue in the unack state or moved to some other error queue or something.  I can see from this question (Request/Response pattern: Stop consumer to reprocess message on application restart) that the messages that are not responded to are removed from the queue.  Is there any way to configure them so that they get moved to a different queue if it fails?  We want to give our DevOps department a method of visibility into the failure rates.  There doesn’t  seem to be anything that pops my attention that something went wrong.
Can you please explain to me the Queue and Exchange mechanism that happens under the hood in the request/response pattern, or give me a link that explains it?
If you’re familiar with Dynatrace, is there a way to see these just by instrumenting the RabbitMQ cluster, or would we need to install a Dynatrace agent on the producer device so that we can watch for these timeout exceptions?
I have tried different percentages.  I don't see an easy way to 'see' that 50% of the messages are not getting responses.
